# FileNotFound error: Path to files referenced in class whose variable is created in another directory

Tags: python, path, pytest

I have to write test scripts for an existing project, the setup of which is as follows (there are multiple .py and .json files):

```
ProjectFolder
    - Somefile.py
    - columns.json
```

Somefile.py has a class SomefileClass, and in the _*init*_ and other member functions, multiple variables are assigned values obtained from data in columns.json and other json files.

I thought it would be best to have the source code in one directory and the tests in another, like so:

```
ProjectFolder
  - src
    - Somefile.py
    - columns.json
  - tests
    - test_Somefile.py
```

I used `sys.path.append("..\src")` to use `from Somefile import SomefileClass` and this works fine.

In test_Somefile.py, I initialize a vairable as so: `sfc_obj = SomefileClass()`. Somefile.py uses `with open('columns.json') as infile` in the _*init*_ method of the class. Therefore, I get this error for the open() statement in Somefile.py:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'columns.json'

How do I fix this? Or should I consider a different structure for the project altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current directory is the one where you start the python script from, but you'd need the directory of the script. That can be done via the `__file__` variable:

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "columns.json"
with open(filename, ...
```

`pathlib` is the modern version of `os.path`. `resolve` makes the path absolute, and `parent` takes the parent, i.e. the directory of the script. The `/` operator then appends the filename itself to that path.

P.S.: The structure is fine. Depending whether and how you like to package it later, it can be good to rename `src` to the name of the package, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pytest framework, you can get the root directory using request.config.rootdir

```
    dir = os.path.abspath(request.config.rootdir + '/src')
    os.path.join(dir, "columns.json"))
```